# How to resolve white flash when action mode visible in android?

Tags: android

I have an app which contains Main activity with multiple tab fragment. Problem is that when action mode gets visible there is white flash occurs at the time of action mode visibility and Invisibility.How do I resolve this issue?

code:-

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: On which version did you get this behavior . Is it same below 21 and above 21 ?

Comment: It is kitkat....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use style below . your style-21 can be as it is .

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Well strange . I have used CAB but didn't get this behavior .